# Cannot get Fixed Action Button to work in Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm following a Materialize CSS tutorial on youtube and am following it's instructions to create a FAB. However, the icons do not appear when i scroll to the button. I'm not sure why that is happening.

I've looked around the internet and have not found a solution to this. It might be an issue with jQuery but i have copied and pasted the HTML setup code exactly from the Materialize website.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed-action-btn">
  <a ref="#" class="btn-floating red btn-large">
    <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
  </a>
   <ul>
        <li><a ref="#" class="btn-floating blue btn-large"><i 
         class="large material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
        <li><a ref="#" class="btn-floating green btn-large"><i 
         class="large material-icons">format_quotes</i></a></li>
        <li><a ref="#" class="btn-floating yellow btn-large"><i 
         class="large material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
        <li><a ref="#" class="btn-floating orange btn-large"><i 
         class="large material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: add your code like jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

You need to include materialize css and js both try this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Jquery to call materialize js as well as need to add materialize css for proper layout and design and add call function for FAB action.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed-action-btn">
  <a ref="#" class="btn-floating red btn-large">
    <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
  </a>
   <ul>
        <li><a ref="#" class="btn-floating blue btn-large"><i 
         class="large material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
        <li><a ref="#" class="btn-floating green btn-large"><i 
         class="large material-icons">format_quotes</i></a></li>
        <li><a ref="#" class="btn-floating yellow btn-large"><i 
         class="large material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
        <li><a ref="#" class="btn-floating orange btn-large"><i 
         class="large material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Materialize doesnt depend on JQuery anymore and you are using 1.0.0 so you need to add the following js function. See https://materializecss.com/floating-action-button.html

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn');
  var instances = M.FloatingActionButton.init(elems, {
    direction: 'top'
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add jQuery in the body section

then after include